# Mongodb shutting down

Tags: mongodb

I have this problem with mongodb shutting down. It is actually throwing a segmentation fault and then shutting down. The error log is given below. Could anyone suggest what is causing the error.

```
Wed May 11 12:50:53 db version v1.6.5, pdfile version 4.5
Wed May 11 12:50:53 git version: 0eb017e9b2828155a67c5612183337b89e12e291
Wed May 11 12:50:53 sys info: Linux domU-12-31-39-01-70-B4 2.6.21.7-2.fc8xen #1 SMP Fri Feb 15 12:39:36 EST 2008 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_37
Wed May 11 12:50:53 [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
Wed May 11 12:50:53 [websvr] web admin interface listening on port 28017
Wed May 11 12:51:03 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:36745 #1
Wed May 11 12:51:03 [conn1] end connection 127.0.0.1:36745
Wed May 11 12:51:05 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:36747 #2
Wed May 11 12:51:05 [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:36747
Wed May 11 12:51:05 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:36748 #3
Wed May 11 12:51:05 [conn3] error: have index [twitter.home_timeline.$aves_user_id_1] but no NamespaceDetails
Wed May 11 12:51:05 [conn3] end connection 127.0.0.1:36748
Wed May 11 12:51:09 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:36752 #4
Wed May 11 12:51:09 [conn4] end connection 127.0.0.1:36752
Wed May 11 12:51:10 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:36753 #5
Wed May 11 12:51:10 [conn5] dropDatabase twitter
Wed May 11 12:51:10 [conn5] query twitter.$cmd ntoreturn:1 command: { dropDatabase: 1 } reslen:74 113ms
Wed May 11 12:51:10 [conn5] end connection 127.0.0.1:36753
Wed May 11 12:51:10 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:36754 #6
Wed May 11 12:51:11 [conn6] end connection 127.0.0.1:36754
Wed May 11 12:51:17 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:36755 #7
Wed May 11 12:51:17 allocating new datafile /home/lakesh/mongodb/data/twitter.ns, filling with zeroes...
Wed May 11 12:51:17 done allocating datafile /home/lakesh/mongodb/data/twitter.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0 secs
Wed May 11 12:51:17 allocating new datafile /home/lakesh/mongodb/data/twitter.0, filling with zeroes...
Wed May 11 12:51:17 done allocating datafile /home/lakesh/mongodb/data/twitter.0, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs
Wed May 11 12:51:17 allocating new datafile /home/lakesh/mongodb/data/twitter.1, filling with zeroes...
Wed May 11 12:51:17 done allocating datafile /home/lakesh/mongodb/data/twitter.1, size: 128MB,  took 0 secs
Wed May 11 12:51:17 [conn7] building new index on { _id: 1 } for twitter.home_timeline
Wed May 11 12:51:17 [conn7] done for 0 records 0secs
Wed May 11 12:51:20 allocating new datafile /home/lakesh/mongodb/data/twitter.2, filling with zeroes...
Wed May 11 12:51:20 done allocating datafile /home/lakesh/mongodb/data/twitter.2, size: 256MB,  took 0 secs
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] building new index on { _id: 1 } for twitter.direct_messages
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] done for 0 records 0secs
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] info: creating collection twitter.direct_messages on add index
building new index on { _id: 1 } for twitter.hash_tags
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] done for 0 records 0secs
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] info: creating collection twitter.hash_tags on add index
building new index on { _id: 1 } for twitter.mentions
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] done for 0 records 0secs
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] info: creating collection twitter.mentions on add index
building new index on { _id: 1 } for twitter.urls
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] done for 0 records 0secs
Wed May 11 12:51:21 [conn7] info: creating collection twitter.urls on add index
building new index on { aves_user_id: 1.0 } for twitter.home_timeline
Wed May 11 12:51:22 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

Wed May 11 12:51:22 Backtrace:
0x84a7552 0xb7730400 0x8102d3e 0x8201dfc 0x820387e 0x83dbf63 0x83874ec 0x8388efd 0x838e3f8 0x839025a 0x8367ad2 0x836998b 0x84a5793 0x81cd468 0x84bf1bd 0xb75d6cc9 0xb75436ae 
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo10abruptQuitEi+0x3c2) [0x84a7552]
 [0xb7730400]
 ./mongod(_ZNK5mongo7BSONObj21getFieldDottedOrArrayERPKc+0xae) [0x8102d3e]
 ./mongod(_ZNK5mongo9IndexSpec8_getKeysESt6vectorIPKcSaIS3_EES1_INS_11BSONElementESaIS6_EERKNS_7BSONObjERSt3setIS9_NS_22BSONObjCmpDefaultOrderESaIS9_EE+0x8c) [0x8201dfc]
 ./mongod(_ZNK5mongo9IndexSpec7getKeysERKNS_7BSONObjERSt3setIS1_NS_22BSONObjCmpDefaultOrderESaIS1_EE+0x24e) [0x820387e]
 ./mongod(_ZNK5mongo12IndexDetails17getKeysFromObjectERKNS_7BSONObjERSt3setIS1_NS_22BSONObjCmpDefaultOrderESaIS1_EE+0x33) [0x83dbf63]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo14fastBuildIndexEPKcPNS_16NamespaceDetailsERNS_12IndexDetailsEi+0x69c) [0x83874ec]
 ./mongod() [0x8388efd]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr6insertEPKcPKvibRKNS_11BSONElementEb+0xbc8) [0x838e3f8]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo11DataFileMgr16insertWithObjModEPKcRNS_7BSONObjEb+0x6a) [0x839025a]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo14receivedInsertERNS_7MessageERNS_5CurOpE+0x3a2) [0x8367ad2]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_8SockAddrE+0x19bb) [0x836998b]
 ./mongod(_ZN5mongo10connThreadEPNS_13MessagingPortE+0x313) [0x84a5793]
 ./mongod(_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvPFvPN5mongo13MessagingPortEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIS6_EEEEEEE3runEv+0x18) [0x81cd468]
 ./mongod(thread_proxy+0x7d) [0x84bf1bd]
 /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x5cc9) [0xb75d6cc9]
 /lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e) [0xb75436ae]

Wed May 11 12:51:22 dbexit: 

Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] closing listening socket: 5
Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] closing listening socket: 6
Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] closing listening socket: 7
Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] closing listening socket: 8
Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] shutdown: going to flush oplog...
Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] shutdown: closing all files...
Wed May 11 12:51:22     closeAllFiles() finished

Wed May 11 12:51:22 [conn7] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Wed May 11 12:51:22 dbexit: really exiting now
Wed May 11 12:51:22 ERROR: Client::~Client _context should be null but is not; client:conn
```

Comment: Which version is this, and what is the OS you're running it on?

Comment: Has this happened more than just the once? It looks like it is trying to abort an executing query when it gets the shutdown signal and may not be an error.

Comment: The db version is 1.4.4 and the OS is ubuntu 64 bit

Comment: Any reason you want to use 1.4.4? Its very old, you might want to try 1.8.x which is the latest and from the days of 1.4.x it has possibly a ton of fixes and enhancements.

Comment: The db version is 1.4.4 and the OS is ubuntu 64 bit. It is happening frequently. Is it because my db has some errors in it. Actually what I am doing is dump the data in bson format from my remote server and then when I import the data using mongorestore I am getting this error and the server crashes down. Everytime I try to import the data the server crashes. Is it that my db taken from remote server has some issues in it

Comment: My local db version is 1.6.4 but still it's not working

Comment: How about you delete the data folder on your server (NOT the remote) and reimport? Please note that you should only do it if you do not care if the data is gone from your server and the data you're restoring from the remote server is all you need on your server. You'd need to shut down your server before you do so.

Comment: lobster1234 I have tried that as well. But it is not working either. I have added the full stack trace in my question. Could u have a look at that. I don't know what the problem is. Could it be that because of the mismatch of the version of db that I am using between my remote server and local one that this problem has occured. The remote is of version 1.4.4 while my local is 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

Here are the 2 options I can think of:

1. Start your local server as a [slave](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Master+Slave#MasterSlave-Slave) to the remote master. Once all the data is replicated on your local, shut it down and bring it back as a regular (master).
2. Start your local server. Use `db.copyDatabase()` or `db.cloneDatabase()`[API](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Copy+Database+Commands) from the command line client to copy that database from the remote server to your local server.

Please give these a try - I am positive you'll see some progress.