# problems in importing mongodb database

Tags: mongodb

I have some problems in importing mongodb database using restore command. I use the normal mongodump command to dump a database and then try to use mongorestore to restore it in my local server. The problem is when the number of documents in a collection are small the import is successful but when the number of documents are larger then the server crashes. A stacktrace of the log is given below

```
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50532 #35
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.ns, filling with zeroes...
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0 secs
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.0, filling with zeroes...
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.0, size: 16MB,  took 0 secs
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.1, filling with zeroes...
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.1, size: 32MB,  took 0 secs
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] building new index on { _id: 1 } for twitter.home_timeline
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] done for 0 records 0secs
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.2, filling with zeroes...
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /var/lib/mongodb/twitter.2, size: 64MB,  took 0 secs
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] building new index on { _id: 1 } for twitter.direct_messages
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] done for 0 records 0secs
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] building new index on { aves_user_id: 1.0 } for twitter.home_timeline
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] done for 3838 records 0.027secs
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] building new index on { parsed: 1.0 } for twitter.home_timeline
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] done for 3838 records 0.03secs
Wed May 11 16:42:14 [conn35] building new index on { parsed: 1.0 } for twitter.direct_messages
Wed May 11 16:42:14 Invalid access at address: 0x11dc218a

Wed May 11 16:42:14 Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).
```

Can anyone tell me the reason behind this. Well the remote server is a 64 bit ubuntu while my local server is 32 bit ubuntu. So could this be the reason for the crash. I mean I have just used simple mongodump and mongorestore that's it, then why is it crashing the server.

Plus I don't understand; mongodb isn't stable or what it is always facing the segmentation fault problem. Any insights??

Comment: How is this not a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959775/mongodb-shutting-down that you asked around the same time?

Comment: Actually I just wanted to know if there could be any problem while restoring data to a 32 bit ubuntu when the dumped mongodb data is from a 64 bit mongodb

Comment: Not unless what you are importing and the existing data adds up to more than 2 GB.

Comment: By the way, please look at the duplicate question you posted where I've tried to answer it.

Comment: lobster1234, I found out that the problem occurs when it tries to import the indexes for a particular collection. Rest is fine. Could u please provide some insights why is it so. I have upgraded the mongodb to version 1.8.1. And it is throwing Segmentation fault in that particular position

Comment: Did you try the copyDatabase or cloneDatabase?

Comment: Well I have already solved the problem. I changed my system to 64 ubuntu as well with a clean install of mongodb. And it just worked fine. This was not the best way to solve it but it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

How large are the collections? Do both servers have the same amount of physical memory? Mongo will store as much of the working set into memory as possible, but if the server you're restoring on has dramatically less RAM it could be causing the problem.